# Universal Windows Apps 8.1 data binding issue

Tags: xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app, mvvm-light, windows-8.1-universal

Simple two way data binding to a model's property is not working, to reproduce the issue, I have created a new project in Visual Studio 2013 i.e. with Blank App (Universal Apps) template with .NET framework 4.5

[Project folders and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/805xF.png)

The model

```
namespace UWP.MVVM.Models
{
    public class PersonModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The base view model

```
namespace UWP.MVVM.Core
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    public class VMBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The INavigable interface

```
namespace UWP.MVVM.Core
{
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    using Windows.Phone.UI.Input;
#endif

    public interface INavigable
    {
        void Activate(object parameter);

        void Deactivate(object parameter);

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        void BackButtonPressed(BackPressedEventArgs e);
#endif
    }
}
```

The main view model

```
namespace UWP.MVVM.ViewModels
{
    using UWP.MVVM.Core;
    using UWP.MVVM.Models;
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    using Windows.Phone.UI.Input;
#endif

    public class MainViewModel : VMBase, INavigable
    {
        private PersonModel person;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.Person = new PersonModel();
        }

        public PersonModel Person
        {
            get
            {
                return this.person;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == this.person)
                {
                    return;
                }

                this.person = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public void Activate(object parameter)
        {
            this.Person.FirstName = "Gerrard";
        }

        public void Deactivate(object parameter)
        {
        }

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        public void BackButtonPressed(BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

The main page view

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWP.MVVM.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWP.MVVM"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="using:UWP.MVVM.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <!--<Page.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>-->

    <Grid Margin="24,24">
        <TextBox Header="First Name" 
                 Text="{Binding Person.FirstName}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The main page code behind

```
namespace UWP.MVVM
{
    using UWP.MVVM.Core;
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    using Windows.Phone.UI.Input;
#endif
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
    using UWP.MVVM.ViewModels;

    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            var navigableViewModel = this.DataContext as INavigable;
            if (navigableViewModel != null)
            {
                navigableViewModel.Activate(e.Parameter);
            }

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
#endif
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            var navigableViewModel = this.DataContext as INavigable;
            if (navigableViewModel != null)
            {
                navigableViewModel.Deactivate(e.Parameter);
            }

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
#endif
        }

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            var navigableViewModel = this.DataContext as INavigable;
            if (navigableViewModel != null)
            {
                navigableViewModel.BackButtonPressed(e);
            }
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

I tried using Mode=TwoWay on the TextBox and it is not working, but when I set the DataContext in xaml instead of the code behind then data binding works even without the Mode=TwoWay property.

I want to set the DataContext in the code behind file as in the real project where I am having this issue, I am using MVVM-light libraries along with its SimpleIoc container, so I want to get the view model instance from SimpleIoc and set the DataContext because the view model dependencies are injected by the SimpleIoc and the code will be a lot cleaner.

Comment: The tag **UWP** should be used only if this question is about developing for the Universal Windows Platform through Windows 10. But you seem to be using VS 2013 which doesn't support UWP development.

Comment: Okay it should be Universal Windows Apps, I got that one wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: you only notify the change of `PersonModel Person`. The ViewModel need to notify the change of the **property** of `PersonModel`.

Since you are using MVVM Light, change your Model to:

```
public class PersonModel : ObservableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    string _FirstName = "";
    public string FirstName {
        get {
            return _FirstName;
        }
        set {
            Set(ref _FirstName, value);
        }
    }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it okay to implement INotifyPropertyChanged both on the ViewModel and the Model here in this context, or should I be implementing it only on the Model?

Comment: MVVM Light has ObservableObject for used in Model and BaseViewModel for ViewModel. Both can be used for notify PropertyChanged. If you want to keep the Model clean, you can raise PropertyChanged for the `Person` property on ViewModel as well: `NotifyPropertyChanged("Person.FirstName");`

Please consider accept my answer if it helps :)